# C# with access as database. Database values in textbox if select Combobox

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

[image: image 1]I have an error where is shows the connection is not closed.
I even tried by putting a finally but yet it does not work

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Dataaa WHERE FirstName='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
        command.CommandText = query;
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            txt_EID.Text = reader["EID"].ToString();
            textBox1.Text = reader["Firstname"].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = reader["LastName"].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = reader["ICNO"].ToString();
            textBox4.Text = reader["Address"].ToString();
            textBox5.Text = reader["Loan"].ToString();
            textBox6.Text = reader["Percent"].ToString();
            textBox7.Text = reader["Payback"].ToString();
            textBox8.Text = reader["StartDate"].ToString();
            textBox9.Text = reader["EndDate"].ToString();
            textBox10.Text = reader["Monthly"].ToString();
            textBox11.Text = reader["PaymentType"].ToString();
            textBox12.Text = reader["Remark"].ToString();

        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error " + ex);
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code in your question as TEXT. Images are difficult to read and impossible to create code to test your problem

Comment: And if you get a connection open error on a global variable of type OleDbConnection then you need to check every part of your code where you forgot to close that connection (for example if you enter a catch block and forget to close the connection)

Comment: For starters, you should always close your connection in finally block.

Comment: Is it possible that an exception the first time around caused the `connection.Close` to be skipped and the exception we see in the screenshot is from the second time around?

Comment: Do you have **any** other code that opens the connection. It would be relevant here too.

Comment: @Steve yes all other part of the connection is closed

Comment: @AkashGill Is that the answer to both of my questions? If you're not using the connection anywhere else, you shouldn't make it a member variable, but rather just use it locally as shown in Jon Barker's answer.

Comment: @NemanjaTodorovic i tried but i still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

instead of doing connection.Close manually, create the connection in a 'Using' block:

`using(var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
     OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
     ........
}`

This way you don't need to worry about closing the connection. As soon as the using block ends, so does the connection.